# ¿Cómo abrir archivos desde cualquier directorio con la función open()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, archivo, interfaz-gráfica

**¡Hola comunidad!**

Tengo la siguiente jerarquía dentro de una carpeta llamada "Proyecto":

```
>Proyecto
>    \images\
>        una_imagen.png
>    __init__.py
>    mi_app.pyw
```

Dentro de la carpeta "Proyecto" se encuentra un archivo llamado `mi_app.pyw` que necesita usar la función `open()` para abrir la imagen PNG contenida en una subcarpeta de "Proyecto" llamada "images".

El código de `mi_app.pyw` es el siguiente:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App:

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()

        i_load = Image.open('una_imagen.png')  # Aquí debo indicar la imagen a cargar
        i_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i_load)

        i = tk.Label(self.root, image=i_image)
        i.pack()
        i.img_ref = i_image

    def mainloop(self):

        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

Al ejecutarse, la intérprete de Python muestra:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'una_imagen.png'
```

La lógica que deseo implementar es que dentro de la carpeta "images" se puedan guardar todas las imágenes e iconos que luego voy a utilizar por `mi_app.pyw`, de modo que sirva como contenedor para esta clase de archivos. Además, quisiera que se pudiera ejecutar `mi_app.pyw` si se llegase a copiar la carpeta "Proyecto" a otro ordenador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque se podría usar una ruta relativa, hay que tener en cuenta que las rutas relativas en Python se resuelven en base al directorio de trabajo actual. Jamás se debe asumir que dicho directorio es (o va a ser en el momento de obtener el recurso) siempre el del script ejecutado, más aún cuando se trabaja o distribuyen paquetes.

Una forma mucho más robusta de resolver las rutas de los recursos es generar la ruta partiendo de la ruta del archivo (script) o paquete ejecutado. Por ejemplo, en tu caso:

```
import pathlib 
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App:

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        image_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).absolute().parent / 'images/una_imagen.png'
        i_load = Image.open(image_path)  # Aquí debo indicar la imagen a cargar
        i_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i_load)

        i = tk.Label(self.root, image=i_image)
        i.pack()
        i.img_ref = i_image

    def mainloop(self):

        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

El atributo especial `__file__` es un atributo de todo módulo que contiene la ruta del script.